# My batch files if else statement isn't working

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

So I have created a file that works and when testing it without the if/else statement. When I put in this in a if statement it doesn't work at all though, is my syntax wrong or what? Thanks.

```
@echo off
set /p id= Folder Name:
set /p yn= Subfolders? (y/n):

If %yn% == "y"
Set rootDirectory = Y:\
md %id

Set rootDirectory = Y:\%id%
md %id%\Source
md %id%\Work
md %id%\PrintFinal

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe %id%

Else
Set rootDirectory = Y:\
md %id%

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe %id%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose the blocks of code within parenthesis.

```
@echo off
set /p id= Folder Name:
set /p yn= Subfolders? (y/n):

If %yn% == "y" (
  Set rootDirectory = Y:\
  md %id%

  Set rootDirectory = Y:\%id%
  md %id%\Source
  md %id%\Work
  md %id%\PrintFinal
) else (
  Set rootDirectory = Y:\
  md %id%
)

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe %id%
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `(` and `)` to group statements.

Call `IF /?` and you will get a help page which describes the syntax of the IF statement

Answer (score -1):

Here's an updated one

```
@echo off
set /p id= Folder Name:
set /p yn= Subfolders? (y/n):

  If %yn% == y
  Set rootDirectory = Y:\
  md %id
```

it works for me

Comment: This will always execute the set and md statements